# pocketsphinx installation error on windows

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

I tried installing the latest pocketsphinx 0.1.0.
For that I downloaded swigwin 3.0.10 unzipped it and added to the system variable "path"
I also installed git which was mentioned as the requirement for installing pocketsphinx on "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pocketsphinx"
After that I changed the directory to the unzipped folder "pocketsphinx 0.1.0"

Then I tried with "pip install pocketshpinx"
It showed the message that system requirement already met

but the package was not successfully installed

Then I tried with "python setup.py install"
It showed the following error:

```
deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx\kws_search.c(462) : error C2143: syntax er
ror : missing ';' before 'type'
deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx\kws_search.c(467) : error C2065: 'n_speech
' : undeclared identifier
deps/pocketsphinx/src/libpocketsphinx\kws_search.c(470) : error C2065: 'n_speech
' : undeclared identifier
error: command '"C:\Users\qayyum\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

Can some one please help me to resolve this error and to install pocketsphinx successfully....

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in pocketsphinx, it does not support compiler you have. You have few choices:

- Update the compiler to more recent version
- Update pocketsphinx, I've just fixed the code, you need to clone [pocketsphinx](http://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx) and [pocketsphinx-python](http://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python) from cmusphinx github.

It will take some time to update pip

Comment: After upgrading compiler and pocketsphinx it showed error at pocketsphinx\__init__.py, line 32, pocketsphinx\pocketsphinx.py,line 42 & line38 and ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: You need to set pythonpath probably